# enable embedded jetty cache static files like css/js 304

Tags: static, jetty, http-status-code-304

Embedded jetty runs as web server, all css & js files are refreshed with 200 code when web page is refreshed from web browser. Expected code for static files like css/js is 304.
How embedded jetty can be configured to enable static files cache? Java code instead of xml is used for configuration. Thanks in advance!

Embedded server is initialized as below,

```
Server server = new Server(80);
HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();
ResourceHandler srcHandler = new ResourceHandler();
srcHandler.setResourceBase("WebRoot\\assets");
handlers.addHandler(srcHandler);
ServletContextHandler contextHandler = new ServletContextHandler();
contextHandler.addServlet(RouterSevlet.class, "/index");
SessionManager sm = new HashSessionManager();
sm.setMaxInactiveInterval(3600);
contextHandler.setSessionHandler(new SessionHandler(sm));
contextHandler.setInitParameter("cacheControl","max-age=3600,public");
handlers.addHandler(contextHandler);
server.setHandler(handlers);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use WebAppContext can resolve the problem.

Comment: How? I have the same problem and a few line of code or a reference would be most appreciated.